# NodeMCU enduser setup module html file that creates another file

Tags: lua, nodemcu

I have created my own enduser_setup.html file nodemcu(for the enduser setup module: https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/modules/enduser-setup/#enduser_setupstart).

I have added another field (beyond the ssid\password fileds):

```
<input id=result1 type=text autocorrect=off autocapitalize=none placeholder='Place ID' />
```

I want on submit to create a lua file (result1.lua) with the Get result of this field.

Tried with php:

```
<?php
    $myfile = fopen("result1.lua", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
    $txt = $_GET["result1"];
    fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    fclose($myfile);
?>
```

Did not work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is currently not possible with NodeMCU. However, there is a [pending pull request](https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/pull/1886) that'll add this feature. It's likely going to be merged to the `dev` branch in the next days.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Happy to hear that!

Comment: Marcel, can you telll me why it is not merged yet?

Comment: My last PR comment says it all.